# accessing element added using jquery append method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am appending an element to div using jquery which I got through ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'api'
}).done(function (e) {
    $.each(e.records, function (index, value) {
        $('#productconatiner').append('<div><a href="#" data-id='+value.id+' class="pimg"></a></div>');
    });
})
```

Now I want to access this anchor tag so I do that using

```
$(document).on('click', '.pimg', function () {
    alert('something');
})
```

and it's working fine.

But now I want to add class to it if specific condition matches so for that I tried lots of things but nothing is working.

So, for example, I want to do that using function so I tried the following way

```
function checkitem() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'api'
    }).done(function (e) {
        $.each(e.records, function (index, value) {
            if ('[data-id=' + value.prid + ']') {
                //do something
            }
        });
    })
}
```

so here if anchor tag with data-id matched then do something

but it not working.
Can anyone help me how to do that?

Comment: `if(your_condition){$('.pimg').addClass('border border-danger');}`

Comment: are you trying to add class after or before you append it?

Comment: I have the same question as @Karl-AndréGagnon. Also, note that since your selector for the addClass function is a class, every element within the DOM that has that class will get the added class *border border-danger*.

Comment: hi Karl-André Gagnon , i want to add class after appending that element

Comment: First of all I recommend to you 2 things, you should use template manager mechanism while import some html to somewhere else, in your current way debugging and readability is diffucult. second recommandation is, binding event  to html element is OK but again handling is quite diffucult. So for example, in your each loop you can add to your html code "... onClick='someJSFunction'.. " that you intented to import, like changing class that html event. If you declare that function or functions in your js file, you don't need to bind any javascript function after getting data from server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all Correct this

```
from this => 
$('#productconatiner').append('<div><a href="#" class="pimg"></div>');

to this => 
$('#productconatiner').append('<div><a href="#" class="pimg"></a></div>');


function checkitem() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'api'
    }).done(function (e) {
        $.each(e.records, function (index, value) {

               $('[data-id=' + value.prid + ']').addClass("border border-danger");

        });
    })
}
```

Comment: i tried this a tag issue then also it not worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate where do you add the classes border, border-danger to pimg? Because only after your ajax request completes, you will pimg in the DOM. Adding a fiddle would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your appended HTML isn't looking quite right, and secondly you should add click event and addClass after append

so your code should look like

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'api'
}).done(function (e) {
    $.each(e.records, function (index, value) {
        $('#productconatiner').append('<div><a href="#" class="pimg">link</a></div>');
        $('.pimg').click(function () {
             // if you want here add class then your addClass goes here
         });
        // If you want to add class based on some condition,
        // then your addClass should goes here
    });
})
```

Comment: actually, I want to do that using function now u can see elaborated question so you can get a clear hint what I want to do